Trying to calculate $\int_{\vert z \vert = 2} \frac z{\cos z}dz$
Trying to calculate $$\int\limits_{\vert z \vert = 2} \frac{z}{\cos z}dz$$ but running into a lot of issues. I decided to try and use $$\int\limits_{\vert z \vert = 2} \frac{z}{\cos{z}}dz = 2 \pi i \cdot {\rm Res\,}\left[\frac{z}{\cos z}, \frac{2n+1}{2} \pi \right]$$ and we have only $n=0, -1$ which gives us the desired singularity that's inside the region $\vert z \vert = 2$. Then, I split it up like this:
$$\int\limits_{\vert z \vert = 2} \frac{z}{\cos{z}}dz = 2 \pi i \cdot \left[{\rm Res\,}\left[\frac{z}{\cos z}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right] + {\rm Res\,}\left[\frac{z}{\cos z}, -\frac{\pi}{2} \right]\right]$$
Then, I calculated ${\rm Res\,}\left[\frac{z}{\cos z}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$ as following:
Use the fact that if $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$, with $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ analytic at $z_0$, with $h'(z_0) \neq 0$ then ${\rm Res\,}\left[f(z), z_0 \right] = \frac{g(z_0)}{h'(z_0)}$
$${\rm Res\,}\left[\frac{z}{\cos z}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right] = \frac{z}{-\sin z}\bigg\vert_{z=\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{-\sin \frac{\pi}{2}} = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Similarly, find that $${\rm Res\,}\left[\frac{z}{\cos z}, -\frac{\pi}{2} \right] = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Then, finally, we have $$\int\limits_{\vert z \vert = 2} \frac{z}{\cos z}dz = 2 \pi i \cdot \left[ (-\frac{\pi}{2}) + (-\frac{\pi}{2}) \right] = -2 \pi ^2 i$$
Now, maybe this is correct, but something tells me that it's almost definitely not. Could anyone provide any insight or hints as to where I went awry in my calculation? Thanks.

That is correct, except that, when you wrote that you only had to take $n\in{0,1}$, you should have written $n\in{0,-1}$ instead.
